# checking missing columns value pair

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named FriendRequests which has columns for e.g. Id, RequestFrom and RequestTo

which has data for e.g

```
Id   RequestFrom                            RequestTo 
1    3C24B040-3CE2-46B6-950F-D76A8275505D   4C668138-BB4F-4228-9946-44DED1851C51
2    4C668138-BB4F-4228-9946-44DED1851C51   3C24B040-3CE2-46B6-950F-D76A8275505D
```

So now i want to find out how many such combinations are missing. For e.g. that table has only one row and the second row is missing.

I have tried this but not working

```
SELECT  RequestTo ,
        RequestFrom ,
        IsPending ,
        IsAccept ,
        ActedDate
FROM    FriendRequests
WHERE   RequestFrom NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                    requestTo
                             FROM   FriendRequests )
```

Comment: I am not getting it. What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  f1.RequestTo ,
        f1.RequestFrom ,
        f1.IsPending ,
        f1.IsAccept ,
        f1.ActedDate
FROM    FriendRequests f1
EXCEPT
SELECT  f1.RequestTo ,
        f1.RequestFrom ,
        f1.IsPending ,
        f1.IsAccept ,
        f1.ActedDate
FROM    FriendRequests f1
JOIN FriendRequests f2
ON f1.RequestFrom = f2.RequestTo
AND f2.RequestFrom = f1.RequestTo
```

Edit: Here is another approach

```
SELECT  f1.RequestTo ,
        f1.RequestFrom ,
        f1.IsPending ,
        f1.IsAccept ,
        f1.ActedDate
FROM    FriendRequests f1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM FriendRequests f2
                    ON f1.RequestFrom = f2.RequestTo
                   AND f2.RequestFrom = f1.RequestTo)
```

It will find all the friend requests that has not been accepted.

Comment: @user1037747 no problem. I also posted a differerent approach. Maybe it works better for you